# Rails 4 - Difference in time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, time, date-difference

I have a start time and end time and i want to calculate the duration of the time difference between those two times.

I have tried to use the following

```
@event.start_time = '13:15'
@event.end_time = '16:00'
@event.duration = ((@event.end_time - @event.start_time)/1.hour)
```

for `2 hours 45 min` it shows `2.75 value`.

I want to show it as 2:45. any idea how i can show that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
duration_in_sec = (@event.end_time - @event.start_time).to_i

@event.duration = "#{duration_in_sec / 3600} hours #{(duration_in_sec % 3600 ) / 60 } min"
```

Comment: whole lotta trouble to do something that Rails already has a solution for:  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-distance_of_time_in_words

Comment: @tagcincy You can post your answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
your value / 1 = 2
(your value % 1) * 60 / 100 = 0.45
```

add to two and it's good :)

Answer (score 2):

Rails has a built-in helper for this, [distance_of_time_in_words](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-distance_of_time_in_words).